# Salesforce buttons on Lightning

Tags: lightning, custom-button

In the clasic Salesforce, I have the next button type URL:

[image]

[image]

In the Opportinity view I add this button correctly and work well:

[image]

But if i change to Lightning experience.... I cant add this button to view:

[image]

The button dont appear in the options:

[image]

¿Any can help me?

Basically I need a button that opens an external page, passing variables such as the opportune ID ...

I tried with javascript button but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your **Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions** section is not overridden in your Page Layout.

If it does not have this text:

> Actions in this section are predefined by Salesforce. You can override the predefined actions to set a customized list of actions on Lightning Experience and mobile app pages that use this layout. If you customize the actions in the Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher section, and have saved the layout, then this section inherits that set of actions by default when you click to override.

Then it is overridden.

If that's the case, you need to put your button from **Mobile & Lightning Actions** in this section, too.